# Search Bar Filter (Nested Array)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How to use a search bar Filter for nested array objects in ionic 4 search bar

ionic version-4.7.1 below I have attached my Filter function but I couldn't use this function to filter objects inside a nested array

```
this.filterData = this.allData.filter(data => {if (data.letter && this.searchTerm) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.child_contacts.length; i++) {
  if (
    data.child_contacts[i].full_name
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
  ) {
    return (
      data.child_contacts[i].full_name
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  }
}
return false;}});
```

here is data that needed to be filtered

```
this.allData=[    { 
     "letter":"A",         
     "child_contact":[
          {"full_name":"First"},
          {"full_name":"second"},
          {"full_name":"third"}
     ]
},
{ 
     "letter":"B",         
     "child_contact":[
          {"full_name":"First second"},
          {"full_name":"Third"}
     ]
},
{ 
     "letter":"C",         
     "child_contact":[
          {"full_name":"Third"}
     ]
}        ]
```

if I search 'First' my expected output would be,

```
[    { 
     "letter":"A",         
     "child_contact":[
          {
                    "full_name":"First"
                  },    
     ]
},
{ 
     "letter":"B",         
     "child_contact":[
                  {
                    "full_name":"First"
                  },    
     ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the complete solution but one problem I can see is you are using `child_contacts` with an `s` in the filter,

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.child_contacts.length; i++) {
```

but the data is `child_contact`:

```
this.allData=[    { 
     "letter":"A",         
     "child_contact":[
          {"full_name":"First"},
          {"full_name":"second"},
          {"full_name":"third"}
     ]
},
```